# Окно без рамки в QML не обновляется автоматически

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquick

Если окну выставить флаг Qt.FramelessWindowHint то оно перестаёт обновляться автоматически.
Наглядное видео https://youtu.be/9LJyJWr1m9M
Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему.

**UPD:**
Моя система linux x64
Проект для примера http://rghost.ru/69VBkk2sr В проекте можно раскомментировать строку с Qt.FramelessWindowHint и цвет экрана перестаёт меняться по нажатию.

Сам код примера:

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    // Try comment and uncomment next line
    flags: Qt.FramelessWindowHint
    width: 640
    height: 480
    color: marea.pressed ? "lightblue" : "orange"
    MouseArea {
        id: marea
        anchors.fill: parent
    }
}
```

Comment: Приведите минимальный пример кода, чтобы люди могли воспроизвести его у себя.

Comment: @ixSci , добавил ссылку на тестовый проект.

Comment: @lirik90 прямо в вопрос добавьте проблемный код

Comment: @Cerbo добавил. Вроде бы как проблема проявляется только на Linux

Comment: А без QML работает?